# Capturing mouse events with CefSharp winforms control

Tags: cefsharp

Can someone help me understand how to go about capturing mouse events when using the CefSharp winforms control?

Comment: You can insert JavaScript into each page that could do this. Could you give more detail about what you are trying to achieve and how you wish to process these events?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't check the following example link in detail, but searching for "global mouse hook" should send you in the right direction.

Example link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C